# My android decode doesn't work with php encode

Tags: php, android, json

I'm wondering what the format of a json is suppose to be since it seems php and android has two different types.

When encode the php, it looks like this:

```
{"id":8435,"name":"Sears"}
{"id":8436,"name":"Sears Appliance Services"}
```

But when I try to decode in android. It comes out as one big string in android (because it's just viewing the source code of the php page).

This is the code:

Php:

echo json_encode($results[$i]);

Android:

```
url = new URL("site");

String param = "arg1=" + URLEncoder.encode("value1", "UTF-8");

conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(param.getBytes().length);
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-    urlencoded");
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
out.print(param);
out.close();

InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
String s;
while ((s = reader.readLine()) != null) {
result += s;
}

JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(result);
```